# python hex hmac md5 of passwords not matching javascript

Tags: python

i have a javascript  password coder

> md5 = hex_hmac_md5(secret, password)

How can i emulate this in python - ive tried md5 but that is not the same value

i got my md5 javascript code from this website:

[Pajs Home](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/instructions.html)

(md5.js)

He states the use is as follows:

> In many uses of hashes you end up
>   wanting to combine a key with some
>   data. It isn't so bad to do this by
>   simple concatenation, but HMAC is
>   specifically designed for this use.
>   The usage is:
>
> hash = hex_hmac_md5("key", "data");
>
> The HMAC result is also available
>   base-64 encoded or as a binary string,
>   using b64_hmac_* or str_hmac_*.
>
> Some other hash libraries have the
>   arguments the other way round. If the
>   JavaScript HMAC doesn't match the
>   value your server library generates,
>   try swapping the order.

I have tried some python like this:

```
> def md5_test(secret, password):
>     
>     return md5(secret+password).hexdigest()
```

Can anyone tell me what the code should be in python to get the same value?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what Python's [`hmac`](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html) module is for, don't use the MD5 function directly.

```
# Right
import hmac
# Note that hmac.new defaults to using MD5
hmac.new("password", "message").hexdigest() # 'f37438341e3d22aa11b4b2e838120dcf'

# Wrong
from hashlib import md5
md5("message"+"password").hexdigest() # 'd0647ee3be62a57c9475541c378b1fac'
md5("password"+"message").hexdigest() # 'c494404d2dd827b05e27bd1f30a763d2'
```

Also take a look at how HMAC is implemented (e.g. on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)).

Comment: so to get the same value as the javascript code i wud use: mport hmac
hmac.new("secret","password").hexdigest(). Thanks.

Comment: It still does not return the same value as the javascript method ??

Comment: Sorry i had the secret and password around the wrong way in my calling method - it now works. Thank you very much, saved me hours!